# How to get locale object in PrestaShop 1.7 template?

Tags: templates, locale, prestashop-1.7

I'm using `Tools::displayPrice()` function in my template files to display formated price with currency, but documentation of this function in new version (1.7.6.0) says:

> ```
> * @deprecated Since 1.7.6.0. Please use Locale::formatPrice() instead
> * @see PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\Locale
> ```

So how do I use `Locale` object in my template?

--
P.S.
PrestaShop official documentation at: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/ is a mess, so if anyone could share a link to some complete and reliable resource I (and many more) would be extremely grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google results:

`Context::getContext()->currentLocale->formatPrice(123.45, 'EUR');`

or e.g. in a module

`$this->context->currentLocale->formatPrice($price, $currencyCode);`

from https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/core_updates/1.7.6/